# Facebook SDK 3.11 - получить пол юзера, который авторизировался

Tags: facebook, xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый вечер. Работаю с  facebook SDK 3.11  и куда-то пропали нужные поля.

Меня интересует:

1. как получить в новом SDK пол юзера, который авторизировался.
2. возможно ли получить EMail не от facebook а тот на котором зарегистрирован аккаунт
3. И есть проблемка с получения дня рождения. Приходит <nul> хоте мое ДР указанно.

Зарание спс.

```
(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView*)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user { 
  self.lblFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.first_name];
  self.lblFirstName.delegate = self;

  self.lblSecondName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.last_name];
  self.lblSecondName.delegate = self;

  self.lblEmail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@facebook.com", user.username]; 
  self.lblEmail.delegate = self;

  self.loggedInUser = user;
}
```

---

Как написал iFreeman нужно запросить необходимые readPermissions.

```
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"/* и все остальное, что еще нужно */]];
```

После чего этот Email можно достать очень просто

```
[user objectForKey:@"email"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что вы забываете запросить необходимые readPermissions. 
Нужно что-то вроде

```
[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"basic_info", @"user_likes", @"user_birthday"/* и все остальное, что еще нужно */]];
```